# Hibernate call stored procedures / stored functions that affect Objects of Bean Classes

Tags: hibernate

I'm switching from JDBC to Hibernate. For that, I'm using annotation based mapping.
I used to call stored function / stored procedures to perform sql operations by taking inputs from GUI of my application.

I've heard that Hibernate does not need to hit the main database every time of transaction. It performs CRUD operations on instances of classes which are mapped to database tables. Can we call stored function and procedures that affect Java bean classes and update main database after some interval?

I used to store ids of product in database by taking name of that product from GUI as parameter of java.sql.CallableStatement. How can I achieve this in Hibernate?

Comment: What you've heard is incorrect. And stored procedures execute in the database itself, so they don't have access to the Java classes of your application.

Comment: So, I've to use hql statementa in java instead of using stored procedures?